# How to exchange data between ASP.NET and Desktop app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, desktop-application

I have (maybe not, ups) simple question about exchange data between that two platforms: ASP.NET and desktop app (best choose for my idea is WinForm, but can be console too).

My project in my mind:

1. ASP.NET Core MVC app
2. Desktop app for share COM ports

*I have embedded system [STM32] on Virtual COM so I wanna only send/get data from this and send/get orders from server*

Send orders via POST/GET etc. is easy, I know.. But! I don't have idea how to send orders to my desktop app, without user interferences.

*I only open this app in background and what I say "only for share port"*

Comment: "ASP.NET Core MVC app with Web Api 2" doesn't make any sense. Web  API is an ASP.NET Framework technology which is not available in ASP.NET Core. What you want is an "ASP.NET Core app", as simple as that.

Comment: For the actual problem, there are many solutions: scheduled GET from the desktop app to the web app; hosting a WCF service in the desktop app and calling it from the web app; hosting an ASP.NET SignalR in the desktop app and calling it from the web app; using a message queue service. Pick what you like best

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ``Web API is not available in ASP.NET Core`` what?

Comment: @UbuntuCore The notion that ASP.NET Core has a WebAPI is a marketing move after they saw people confused about it. ASP.NET Core mixed MVC with WebAPI into a single product.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What's wrong with using it to returning http status codes, jsons and executing commands?

Comment: @UbuntuCore It's not wrong, but it's not "ASP.NET Core Web Api 2", it's "ASP.NET Core"

Comment: Yes, They mixed. I say "Web Api", for more specific description of my problem. Scheduled is the easier but it's only part solution.. Ok, I will check your tips, thank you very much :D

Comment: You are asking how to send notifications to clients. There are several HTTP-based options: Webhooks, web sockets, Server-sent events, long polling, SignalR (which uses the last three)

Comment: Your actual scenario though is IoT-based. In these cases pub/sub queues and brokers are often used, especially if there are a *lot* of events and/or a lot of clients. Anything that supports AMQP would be a great idea, eg Qpid. Non-AMQP implementations like ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ are also good options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous alternatives that you could use to accomplish this. As a general field, this is called Interprocess Communication (IPC).

From all approaches, I find embedding a web server into a Winforms application the most flexible and easier solition but please, bear in mind that it's my personal choice. I'll try giving you other possible solutions on this post, though:

### 1. Embedd a server within your Winforms application

This is my personal choice. You can digg into this topic by searching more about embedding a HTTP server into Winforms but here are some links that might give a direction on this:

- [Can a Winforms/WPF app act as HTTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439814/can-a-winforms-wpf-app-act-as-http-server)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2
- [Can a Winforms/WPF app act as HTTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439814/can-a-winforms-wpf-app-act-as-http-server)

Using this approach you'll end up with a full AspNet application and a lightweight web app that integrated directly with desktop code. You'll integrate those two as if you're integrating two web servers: using HTTP calls and more.

### 2 - Named pipes & TCP

Named pipes are very interesting but you should carefully choose between them or TCP communication as each has it's own pros and cons.
You can find an example of Names Pipe / TCP here:
https://github.com/jacqueskang/IpcServiceFramework

For more information about `named pipe` vs `tcp` pros and cons, I've found this post to be really useful: http://saurabhsinhainblogs.blogspot.com/2015/09/what-is-difference-between-tcp-ip-and-Named-Pipes.html

### 3 - Message queues

It's like a silver bullet. A huge and heavy silver bullet but still, a silver bullet. This works fine with, well, pretty much any type of interprocess communication as you'll have a third player in charge of receiving and trasmitting messages and both players (server / client) will listen or publish to this queue.
You can check [NetMQ](https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [MSMQ](https://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-o-msmq-microsoft-message-queuing/5131), [RestBus](http://restbus.org/), [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) or you can even build your own based on SQL Server for instance (although I'd not recommend that unless you're really sure of what you're doing).

### 4 - Others

You have sockets, files (with automatic monitoring physical file system) and many other possible approaches to perform integration without user interaction. Even if I put here 20 other approaches, I'd likely be missing 20 others. Just search for `AspNet Core Interprocess Communication` and you'll find plenty resources about that :)

## Some other useful resources:

This post has a reliable compilation of liks that will help on each IPC approach you might wish to test: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net